# Invalid Geometry Error after ST_ConvexHull

Tags: postgis, qgis, convex-hull

I've a Postgis table of around 80,000 points and want to be able to populate a second table summarizing the data with convex hulls based on points with a common attribute.

For example, the data contains the telephone exchange which each point is associated with - I want to create a convex hull for all points in each telephone exchange. It ought to create around 1000 overlapping polygons.

I tried using the normally excellent QGis ftools convex hull plugin with the option to create hulls based on an input field but my computer spent 6-hours maximising 3 of the four cores before crashing QGis.

And I've tried doing it directly in sql:

> INSERT INTO new_table(exchange_name, the_geom)
>       SELECT exchange_name, ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) As the_geom
>         FROM first_table
>     GROUP BY exchange_name

But this complains about invalid geometry - I've tried geometry constraints of "MULTIPOLYGON" and generic "GEOMETRY" so not sure why this should happen - the source table loads perfectly in QGis.

The Grass "v.hull" tool only creates a convex hull for all points and not based on an attribute.

Any tips or suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: This might be a dumb question - with the added validation, there appears to be nothing wrong with the SQL syntax - running the statement without the INSERT so its just a SELECT creates what to the eye looks like a perfectly good result. So my logic suggests perhaps there may be something wrong with the geometry CONSTRAINT on the target table. What geometry type is created by ST_Convexhull? I've assumed MULTIPOLYGON and tried GEOMETRY.

Comment: Just to add one more detail. When I remove the geometry constraint from the target table and run the statement it successfully populates the new table, and loads perfectly in QGis. But if I try to add the constraint, if gives an error:         ALTER TABLE bt_nga_exchange_mar11 ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON'::text OR the_geom IS NULL);        ERROR:  check constraint "enforce_geotype_the_geom" is violated by some row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

my guess is that you get invalid polygons because one or more groups only have one or two points. that can not make a convexhull polygon.

if that is the problem you can exclude the problematic groups with something like

```
INSERT INTO new_table(exchange_name, the_geom)
SELECT exchange_name, ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) As the_geom
FROM first_table
GROUP BY exchange_name 
having count(*)>=3;
```

if there is rows in the original table with multipoints you will need to count the points in the collection instead:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(exchange_name, the_geom)
SELECT exchange_name, ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) As the_geom
FROM first_table
GROUP BY exchange_name 
having st_npoints(st_collect(the_geom))>=3;
```

I am not by a computor to try, but I think it should work.

HTH
Nicklas

Comment: Thanks - a very good point and one that makes me feel slightly foolish that I hadn't thought of. I ran the SELECT with both your suggestions which worked perfectly but there were no collections with 2 or fewer points - most have several hundred.

Comment: What do you get from:   SELECT ST_NPoints(st_collect(the_geom)) FROM first_table
GROUP BY exchange_name order by ST_NPoints(st_collect(the_geom)) LIMIT 1;

Comment: Just "1" - I'm afraid my knowledge of PostGis has just expired - what does this tell me?

Comment: it just tells you that you have at least 1 group with only one point. it was a double check that you said you had no group with 2 or less points. apparently you ddo and that seems to be your problem. to see all problematic groups and their exchange_name you can run: SELECT exchange_name, ST_NPoints(st_collect(the_geom)) FROM first_table GROUP BY exchange_name having st_npoints(st_collect(the_geom)) < 3;

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I don't know what was going on but I re-ran the SQL you suggested and it worked perfectly this time with no complaints. The problem was clearly somewhere between the keyboard and my chair.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the input data against ST_IsValid?

Example: select exchange_name from first_table where ST_IsValid(the_geom)=false

If any rows are returned then you have invalid geometries and you have to either fix them or exclude them from the above query.

Comment: Thank you - I did as you said, and found a small number of points with no geometry as opposed to corrupt geometry but sadly it made no difference to the result. As a newly learnt example of good practice, I've added the line ST_IsValid(the_geom)=TRUE to the WHERE clause so it makes sure I'm only working with good geometry while I continue to debug.